# an integer is required (got type tuple) Error

Tags: python

I am recieving below error in `Python 3`
any idea?

```
clientDtSocket.send(bytes(fileName,"UTF-8"),("localhost",8101))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

Comment: Please post your code; not all of us are psychic.

Comment: Is not `("localhost", 8101)` a tuple? Is this your intended argument?

Comment: I'd also guess it's an issue passing `("localhost",8101)` to the `send` method.

Comment: How was `clientDtSocket` initialized?

Comment: Please note that `"127.0.0.1"` is usually faster than `"localhost"`, because the latter does an extra DNS lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `clientDtSocket.sendto` instead of `clientDtSocket.send`:

```
clientDtSocket.sendto(bytes(fileName,"UTF-8"),("localhost",8101))
```

More info about these methods: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html